# How do I use my pro in Arena?

Tags: fifa-13

I'd like to use my pro in Arena, but I'm unable to do so. When I search for my player in my team I cannot find him!

Any idea how to do it? I'm currently playing in AC Milan, but on loan in another team.

Comment: Have you figured out how to put a pro in offline-multiplayer? I think that might be a prerequisite for the arena thingy.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In 12, you could play with the team that your pro was assigned to (not in a career). I used the guy to bash my friends because he was in my favorite team. If what you are asking is possible at all, I believe that the current savegame team is not relevant, meaning it doesn't matter if you're on loan because you can have two careers with the same guy, create multiple savegames and so on. Ist must be the team you chose at the time of creation. (Did you? I cannot remember).

Comment: I tried to look into that. But I cannot find him even there. Weird.

Comment: I am pretty sure your "pro" doesn't work like this in fifa 13. He is just there for the duration of career. You cannot even re-use a pro if you start a new "player" career mode - you have to make another one and start from scratch, this also explains why you cannot choose the age your pro starts at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use your pro in the arena in Fifa 13, not like you could in 12.

Your pro online exists in either your single player pro career mode game, or online in the pro game modes. He will not be part of any team outside of those modes, and thus you are unable to select him for the arena.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use your online pro in any modes, I haven't really try the arena though. To use your pro in manager career mode you first have to back up your fifa 13 game saves to any hard drive via USB since you'll have to delete the present one.
To get him in; delete your Online pro data in save games(after backed up) and also delete your matchday, EASFC catalog, Game face(if any), preferred squad, and profile.
After that is done, restart your ps3, go into pro clubs, create a pro with the position you do like him to play in your career, then continue and your previous Pro rating should re-apply to the new pro. Now go to Customize and enter the rooster update and update to the latest EA updates. Afterwards, go back to pro clubs and download your game face, apply it and go into drop-in start a match, then u can quit, now go back to edit players and you will see your pro in free agents, now assign him to any club you want and start a new manager mode career. His country will be what you assigned him when creating him, so chose wisely. You can also increase his overall on the edit and remember, his stats will never improve. This is because EA locked that to online play, but my pro is 5'11 and 158lbs with 88 overall as a ST. This is easy to do, and my explanation is the best way I can exercise it. Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Go to customize fifa > edit team > put your player from subtitute to starting 11 > enjoy

Answer (score -1):

you cant do it i tried... but what you can do is put your pro's stats in to a player that you create on the "customize Menu" and then put that player on the team you play for on your career, then move him from your reserves to the starting eleven, then start a new career, select "use Player" and choose him. (make sure hes the same age, or just make him young and then his overall will go up alot.